# Formatted Write to file in WINAPI

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, winapi, io

With `WriteFile` command, I am trying to write to file in the design I wish. The problem is I have to write to file using a string, or a buffer.

I have to print in the format:

```
a1   a2   a3   a4   a5
b1   b2   b3   b4   b5
.
.
.
```

and these are double types. The major problem I am having is concatenating strings and numbers. If that is possible I could simply do, (if let's say + is the operator, we could:)

```
a1^"   "^a2^"   "^   "^a4"\n".
```

and loop but I do not have that option.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Look up std::wstringbuf for your string construction needs. It allows a syntax very similar to what you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) (or `std::wostringstream` for wide characters) to format the data into a string then write it out to the file.

```
std::ostringstream strm;
double a = 1.1;
double b = 2.2;
strm << "hello " << a << " world " << b;

DWORD written;
WriteFile(handle, strm.str().c_str(), strm.str().size(), &written, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pre-format the data into a buffer. If you can really only use the WinAPI, you could do that with `wsprintf`. Then, when you have a buffer full of data formatted correctly, write the whole thing to disk at once with `WriteFile`. By itself, however, `WriteFile` doesn't have any formatting or conversion capabilities at all.